# Storing/Calculating date/time with JS

Tags: javascript, date, time, date-arithmetic

What is the best practice for saving some time informations in JS?

In my case I want to save the datetime as a user account is created. 36h after creating the account I want to show a message to the user.

Right now I'm saving a timestamp with `new Date().getTime();`. But maybe it is possible to calculate for some events just with `new Date()`?

This is how I do it, but it feels not very elegant - especially for complex calculations.

```
var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
if ( (timeRegistrated + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 36 - currentTime) >= 0 ) {
    console.log('36h are over...');
}
```

I think I have to use some library for complex calculations (like current age of user or how many months between two dates)... But still the basic question: Which type of date-data should be used for the DB?

Comment: well you can try `+new Date() > timeRegistered`. Also, if your code is working and  objective of this question is improvements/optimization, you should try codereview instead

Comment: For the DB the timestamp is universal. Stick to it. The only better option is if your DB has a dedicated Datetime format. Also avoid adding dependencies (libraries) to your code, unless you really need them. Being more elegant in an isolated place is not a reason to include a library. You can be more elegant by organizing your code a bit better, as an alternative.

Comment: Elegance is in the eye of the coder: `if (new Date() - timeRegsitered > 1.296e8)` is concise and obvious. Comments in the code will help. The logic in the OP is not correct, if the test returns true then less than 36 hours have elapsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moment.js has a fromNow function. It's way easier.

http://momentjs.com/

```
moment("20111031", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow();
```

Comment: How would I save the current Date with momentJS (registration moment of new user)? Does it matter?

Comment: Momentjs can parse it so just save the date however you want. new Date() should work perfect. Actually I would probably keep it unformatted as it already is for the database and use moment js to format the data.

Comment: Way easier than what? There is no example here of how to use *fromNow* to determine if the date was 36 hours ago. Given a date and time string of 36 hours ago, `moment(timestring).fromNow()` returns "2 days ago", how should that be compared to say `1456392547709`?